# How to maintain user password in oracle 9i even after database refresh?

Tags: database, oracle, passwords

Every month we will have a database refresh so I assume user accounts are deleted and when that happens we will recreate again the users and provide another batch of passwords. For convenience sake, is there a way that passwords used by the user will be retained after the refresh so we dont need to set another batch of password each time the refresh happens? This is tiresome task especially if many users are involved. Thanks for helping. Or user accounts retained after refresh?

[EDIT]

My senior said that all user accounts will be deleted during the refresh. We can reset the password but its tiresome because we have to email the users their new password.

Comment: How is the refresh being performed? An export/import wouldn't drop users unless you were doing that explicitly before the import, for example. Why don't you just have a script to recreate the users though, and/or reset the passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will all depend on what you call "database refresh".

At the very least, you might somehow save the hashed user password before beginning the "refresh" process, and then restore them at the end.

The following query will use [`dbms_metadata.get_ddl`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#sthref3535) to return a list of SQL *statements* that you might use to *restore* the various password (hashed) values:

```
-- in SQL*plus use the following lines so CLOB are not truncated:
-- SET LONG 3000
-- SET LIN 200
-- COLUMN USERCREATE FORMAT A200

select
   dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', username) || '/' usercreate
from
   dba_users;
```

On my test system (Oracle 11g Express Edition), this will produce something like that:

```
   CREATE USER "SONIA" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'S:A4CA3.....596'
      TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"/
   CREATE USER "SYLVAIN" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'S:23FFA.....8B0'
      DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
      TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"/
   ...
```

Comment: can this query be enhanced and include the priviledges of the users?

Comment: can this query be enhanced and include the priviledges of the users? @Sylvain

Comment: @Norie I can't answer you. But feel free to _ask an other _question_.